# iText table is not getting rendered

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to make a table starting from a map with a list as value. Each list has 2 Strings in them

```
public class Table{

    public static PdfPTable createTable( HashMap<Integer,List<String>> map ){   

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2); // 2 is the number of columns 

        for( int i = 1 ; i == map.size() ; i++ ){ 
             PdfPCell leftCell  = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(map.get(i).get(0))); 
             PdfPCell rightCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(map.get(i).get(1))); 

             table.addCell( leftCell ); 
             table.addCell( rightCell ); 
        }

        return table; 
    }
}
```

I'm sure the data is in the map, but it seems that the table is empty. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop is incorrect:

```
for ( int i = 1 ; i == map.size() ; i++ )
```

What you want

```
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= map.size() ; i++ )
```